# Scala How to create an Array of defs/Objects and the call those defs in a foreach?

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of Scala objects with def's that do a bunch of processing

```
Foo\CatProcessing (def processing)
Foo\DogProcessing (def processing)
Foo\BirdProcessing (def processing)
```

Then I have a my main def that will call all of the individual Foo\obj defProcessing.  Passing in common parameter values and such

I am trying to put all the list of objects into an Array or List, and then do a 'Foreach' to loop through the list passing in the parameter values or such.  ie

```
foreach(object in objList){
   object.Processing(parametmers)
}
```

Coming from C#, I could do this via binders or the like, so who would I manage this is in Scala?

Comment: I'd suggest you read about fundamental scala collection operations. Just as a hint, take a look at what `map` method does on a list. Also, the question is not related to python, so please consider removing the python tag.

Comment: This can be solved in multiple ways. A couple of questions: Do you want to have a list of objects and then call the method on all of them? Or do you want to have a list of functions? What is the output of the functions, `Unit`? What do they receive as input, nothing? - Do you want to collect the results or just execute them?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, a list/array of objects, then I want to iterate over the list. On each iteration call the def/function in that object passing it in parameter values.   Correct, the output is Unit.  For the values/inputs, it's a variety of values. Paths, timestamps, sparksession, ect.  And no need to collect the results after execution, at least not at this time.

Comment: What is "a def"? There is no such thing in Scala as "a def"? What is the backslash meant to signify? Backslashes are illegal in Scala identifiers. Also, `object` is a reserved word in Scala, so your code is not valid.

Comment: @aminmal SWEET! I figured it out with your hint!!!!
   ' val test = Map("foobar" -> CatProcessing)

    test.values.foreach(
      (movie) => movie.processing(sparkSession)
    )'

Comment: Thanks but I actually didn't mean the Map collection type, I meant the map method on lists and other iterables. But also, it turned out that the `processing` thing also returns Unit, so `map` would not be a good idea, you can use the `foreach` on your list directly

Comment: @AminMal haha, thanks for the additional hint :).  I think I understand what you're getting at `animalsArray.map(processing)   animalsArray.foreach(x => (spark, inputRoot, outputRoot, reportDate))

Answer (score 3):

```
for (obj <- objList) {
  obj.processing(parameters) // `object` is a reserved keyword in Scala
}
```

or

```
objList.foreach(obj => obj.processing(parameters))
```

They are actually the same thing, the former being "syntactic sugar" for the latter.

In the second case, you can bind the only parameter of the anonymous function passed to the `foreach` function to `_`, resulting in the following

```
objList.foreach(_.processing(parameters))
```

`for` comprehensions in Scala can be quite expressive and go beyond simple iteration, if you're curious you can read more about it [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-loops.html).

Since you are coming from C#, if by any chance you have had any exposure to [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) you will find yourself at home with the Scala Collection API. The official documentation is quite extensive in this regard and you can read more about it [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/introduction.html).

---

As it came up in the comments following my reply, you also need the objects you want to iterate to:

1. have a common type that
2. exposes the `processing` method

Alternatively, Scala allows to use structural typing but that relies on runtime reflection and it's unlikely something you really need or want in this case.

You can achieve it by having a common trait for your objects, as in the following example:

```
trait Processing {
  def processing(): Unit
}

final class CatProcessing extends Processing {
  def processing(): Unit = println("cat")
}

final class DogProcessing extends Processing {
  def processing(): Unit = println("dog")
}

final class BirdProcessing extends Processing {
  def processing(): Unit = println("bird")
}

val cat = new CatProcessing
val dog = new DogProcessing
val bird = new BirdProcessing

for (process <- List(cat, dog, bird)) {
  process.processing()
}
```

You can run the code above and play around with it [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/iL2TGRanQam5BtVQ73KBGA).

Comment: arg...this is only working if I have 1 item in the Array/list ect.  Otherwise it says "cannot resolve symbol processing".

Comment: How's your list defined? I guess there's no common super type to all the items?

Comment: `var animalsArray = Array(catsProcessing, //dogsProcessing)

    for (obj <- deltasArray)
      {
        obj.processing()
      }
    deltasArray.foreach(_.processing())
    deltasArray.foreach(obj => obj.processing())`

Comment: @GaëlJ `var animalsArray = Array(catsProcessing, //dogsProcessing)`.  When commented out, the for's can access `.processing`.  When I uncomment out dogs, it says it can't resolve the symobol.    I've also checked and rechecked that both functions have identical signatures

Comment: signature is essentially `object catProcessing {def processing(spark: SparkSession,.....`

Comment: @Tdawg90 it doesn’t work because all the objects are not of the same type. You should either extract the process thing into a trait, and make your objects extend that trait (I’d recommend this), or use structural typing (not something I’d go for in this case)

Comment: @AminMal Thanks, I was guessing it was going to be something along those lines.  Being super new at this (umm, about 3 days in :) ), I'll look into how to extract the process into a trait as you suggest.   To answer your other question on Linq, yeah I've used Linq for a long time now, just getting over the structure and syntax Scala/Java/Python is a bit of a learning curve for me.  I appreciate the help and recommendations alot.

Comment: I added a full example that does what you want and linked it to a sandbox on Scastie where you can play around with the code.

Answer (score -3):

Using a Map instead, you can do it as such.  (wonder if this works through other types of lists)

```
val test = Map("foobar" -> CatProcessing)

test.values.foreach(
  (movie) => movie.processing(spark)
)
```